# Jenkins on GCE not building

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm trying to get my head around Jenkins CD and k8s on GCE. I'm following the tutorial on GCE: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-container-engine

For some reason the app won't build:
[image]

This is the Jenkins console output.

This is my Jenkins file:

```
node {
  def project = 'xxxxxx'
  def appName = 'gceme'
  def feSvcName = "${appName}-frontend"
  def imageTag = "eu.gcr.io/${project}/${appName}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

  checkout scm

  sh("echo Build image")
  stage 'Build image'
  sh("docker build -t ${imageTag} .")

  sh("echo Run Go tests")
  stage 'Run Go tests'
  sh("docker run ${imageTag} go test")

  sh("echo Push image to registry")
  stage 'Push image to registry'
  sh("gcloud docker push ${imageTag}")

  sh("echo Deploy Application")
  stage "Deploy Application"
  switch (env.BRANCH_NAME) {
    // Roll out to canary environment
    case "canary":
        // Change deployed image in canary to the one we just built
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#eu.gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${imageTag}#' ./k8s/canary/*.yaml")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/services/")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/canary/")
        sh("echo http://`kubectl --namespace=production get service/${feSvcName} --output=json | jq -r '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip'` > ${feSvcName}")
        break

    // Roll out to production
    case "master":
        // Change deployed image in canary to the one we just built
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#eu.gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${imageTag}#' ./k8s/production/*.yaml")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/services/")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=production apply -f k8s/production/")
        sh("echo http://`kubectl --namespace=production get service/${feSvcName} --output=json | jq -r '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip'` > ${feSvcName}")
        break

    // Roll out a dev environment
    default:
        // Create namespace if it doesn't exist
        sh("kubectl get ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME} || kubectl create ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
        // Don't use public load balancing for development branches
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#LoadBalancer#ClusterIP#' ./k8s/services/frontend.yaml")
        sh("sed -i.bak 's#eu.gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${imageTag}#' ./k8s/dev/*.yaml")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=${env.BRANCH_NAME} apply -f k8s/services/")
        sh("kubectl --namespace=${env.BRANCH_NAME} apply -f k8s/dev/")
        echo 'To access your environment run `kubectl proxy`'
        echo "Then access your service via http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/${env.BRANCH_NAME}/services/${feSvcName}:80/"
  }
}
```

Could someone please lead me into the right direction? I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from the error that problem is on creating symlink for the dockerfile which does not exist. Trace the given location and check if file exist and have required permission.

Answer (score 0):

Absolut Fail. Forgot Dockerfile...